# Monotonic property of solution of a linear (second-order) differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, monotone-functions, monotone-class-theorem

Consider the following differential equation
\begin{equation}
y''+q(t) y=0 ,
\end{equation}
where q(t) is a continuous function $\leq 0\;\; \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$.

I'm trying to prove that each non-constant solution such that $y(0)=0$ is strictly monotone.

I have tried integrating between 0 and t but in this way I can't show anything useful in fact by using the weighted average theorem I get
\begin{equation}
y'(t)=y'(0)-y(\xi_t)\int_{0}^{t}q(x)dx .
\end{equation}
I'm wondering if I should continue to prove that $y'>$ or $<0$ in a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ or if I should use a different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Show that if there is $a\in {\Bbb R}$ for which $y(a)>0$ (or $y(a)<0)$ and $y'(a)=0$ then $(a,y(a))$ must be a global minimum (or maximum) and get a contradiction.

Comment: There is no equivalence. However, the result is in fact stronger. If you prove the statement then the conclusion is that the derivative never vanishes (and this is the case unless $y(0)=y'(0)=0$ and the function is constant).

Comment: That's ok: So, if $y(0)=y'(0)=0$ then $y\equiv 0$ is a solution whence the unique solution. So $y'(0)\neq 0$. Suppose e.g. $y'(0)>0$ and that $y'(x)$ vanishes for some  positive $x$. Take the smallest such, say at $a>0$. Then $y(a)>0$ (why?) and using the ODE you may now construct a contradiction.

Comment: I have made the hint more precise (and perhaps useful). You may also simply finish the arguments in my previous remark.

Comment: For those who wonder: The minimum (or maximum) in the hint is global, though not necessarily unique (unless $q<0$).

Comment: I really don't know how it can be proved that it should be a _global_ minimum (or maximum) but I think the argument (a little bit modified) works just with a _local_ extremum. 
Thanks for the hint!

Comment: By $y(a)$ being e.g. a global minimum I mean that $y(x)\geq y(a)$ for all $x$. This is true since $y$ must be increasing (not necessarily stricly) for $x\geq a$ and decreasing for $x\leq a$.

Comment: That's the correct definition of global minimum but I mean that I can't see no evidence for claiming that it is the case: I can show that $y(a)\geq 0$ and hence that $y''(a)\geq 0$ so that there exists an interval around $a$ where it is a minimum but I can't show it is true $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In my hint I assumed $y(a)>0$. Does that help you? In fact if $y(a)=0$ and $y'(a)=0$ then $y$ is identically zero (simply because $y\equiv 0$ is a solution, and is unique).

Comment: Actually not, because I know that in the interval $[0,a+\delta]$ (if $a>0$ and $\delta$ is sufficiently small) $y\geq 0$ and under suitable condition for $q$ (that forces to distinguish different cases also for the behaviour of $q$), it is true for $x\geq 0$...but I think it wouldn't be the same for $x\leq 0$.

Comment: The origin is irrelevant for for the argument (it only enters later when concluding). Hint 2: Suppose $y(a)>0$, $y'(a)=0$ and  let $I=(b,c)$ be the maximal open interval containing $a$ for which $y(x)> 0$ for all $x\in I$. Then $y$ is convex on $I$ (by the ode) whence decreasing (increasing) to the left (right) of $a$. Suppose $b>-\infty$. By continuity and monotonicity: $y(b)=\lim_{x\rightarrow b^+} y(x)\geq y(a)>0$ but then you may choose $b$ smaller so $I$ was not maximal. Conclude that if the solution goes through $(0,0)$ either it is identically zero, or the derivative never vanishes.